# Route from AKL to YVR?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, routes, yvr, akl

I'm attempting to find out which airline routes exist from AKL (Auckland) (or CHC(Christchurch)) to YVR (Vancouver)? Or companies which fly between those cities, I guess.

So far, I've identified Qantas, Air Pacific, Air NZ, Air Canada, United, and occasionally Korean Air although the latter is generally horrendously priced.  Air Pacific looks to be my best bet thus far, but even that for the month of April is looking painful, so trying to exhaust other leads.

The trick is I'm flying early April to YVR, and then back in October.  The return part is easy enough to find reasonable prices for, but getting there certainly isn't...

Comment: Mention prices you're getting now / what target price you want.

Comment: I didn't want it to turn into a shopping question, but currently NZD$2400 from CHC, or NZ$2200 from AKL is my best ;)

Comment: Air Canada non-stop I am getting ~US$2400 right now.  ~US$2100 via Sydney.  I came up with about ~US$1900 Through LAX from AKL.  At current exchange rates about NZD2200

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as information may be out of date

Comment: @Karlson How is that a reason to close?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Constructing itinerary for a past date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to play with your dates.  Beginning of April will put you into Easter travel time, but for example April 18 to October 2nd would make the ticket through Brisbane and LAX in the range of about US$1800, which at the current exchange rate would be about NZD$2070.  On Kayak.

**EDIT**

One more thing.  Consider buying AKL -> LAX and LAX -> YVR separately.

Comment: yeah I was aware of that, but it's actually quite important that I leave earlier if I want to maintain my non-resident tax status.  Pretty much after Easter weekend is my deadline :/  Thanks for checking that though, I'd not looked at via Brisbane.